# How to Avoid resizing image in "Plugin.Media" nuget?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I created a project in Xamarin form and I want to select a photo from the gallery in a part of it and display it in a image tag.
first i add Plugin.Media from nuget.

my code is :

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(mediaOption);                       
img.Source = file.Path;
```

but my problem is when picture selected and showed, picture is very small!
I use :

```
var mediaOption = new PickMediaOptions()
        { 
            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Large,
            CompressionQuality = 100,
            CustomPhotoSize = 100
        };
```

but that no work!

How i can Avoid resizing image?

Comment: Any reason why not using the built-in [Media Picker from Xamarin Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/media-picker) ?

Comment: @Cfun I used it, but there is also a problem with the size.

Comment: CustomPhotoSize is what is resizing it to 100px

Answer (score 1):

Resizing photo size can be accomplished by adjusting the PhotoSize property on the options.

The easiest is to adjust it to Small, Medium, or Large, which is 25%, 50%, or 75% or the original.

```
var mediaOption = new PickMediaOptions()
    { 
        PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Large,//Resize to 75% of original
        CompressionQuality = 100,
    };
```

If you want to set to a custom percentage, you could use the `Custom` for the `PhotoSize` property. The 100 value in your code is not used for the 100px.

```
var mediaOption = new PickMediaOptions()
    { 
       PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Custom,
       CustomPhotoSize = 100, //Resize to 100% of original
        CompressionQuality = 100,
    };
```